# Difference equations and Jordan form

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a system of difference equations for which I have to find the general solution. I have put them in matrix form to get:-

$x_{k+1}=A \, x_k$, where
$$
A = \pmatrix{3&-1&0\\1&1&0\\1&-1&2}
$$

($x_{k+1}$ and $x_k$ are vectors).

I have calculated that this matrix has eigenvalue 2 (multiplicity 3) and eigenvector (1,1,0).

I originally wanted to use a method we learnt in a lecture, however this requires a Leslie matrix which I realise this is not.

One idea I had was to put the matrix into Jordan form as I realise it cannot be diagonalised but I am struggling. Clearly the nullspace of (A-2I) has dimension one so I moved on to (A-2I)^2 which I calculated to be the the zero matrix so obviously the nullspace is all of R^3.

How can I proceed?

Thank you, and apologies for the poor notation!

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly found, $2$ is the only eigenvalue of $A$.  We find
$$
A - 2I = 
\pmatrix{
1&-1&0\\
1&-1&0\\
1&-1&0
}
$$
You should find that the null space has dimension $2$ (not dimension $1$) with basis consisting of eigenvectors $v_1 = (1,1,0)^T$ *and* $v_2 (0,0,1)^T$.

We need a generalized eigenvector in order to put $A$ into Jordan form.  We find
$$
(A - 2I)x = v_2
$$
has no solution.  However,
$$
(A - 2I)x = v_1 \implies\\
\pmatrix{
1 & -1 & 0 & | & 1\\
1 & -1 & 0 & | & 1\\
1 & -1 & 0 & | & 0
}
$$
so that we can take our generalized eigenvector to be (for example) $x = (1/2,-1/2,0)$.  We can then write $A = SJS^{-1}$ with
$$
J = \pmatrix{2&1&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&2}, \quad
S = \pmatrix{
1&1/2&0\\
1&-1/2&0\\
0&0&1}
$$

Comment: does (A-2I)x = v1 really work with the vector (1/2, -1/2, 0)? I have a similar problem and am stuck because the system for finding generalized eigenvector has no solution.

Comment: @milez you're right, I seem to have made a mistake.  What we're looking for a non-zero vector $v$ within the span of $v_1,v_2$ (this $v$ is itself an eigenvector for $\lambda = 2$) for which $(A - 2I)x = v$ does have a solution, and then we'll take $v$ as the eigenvector and $x$ as the corresponding generalized eigenvector.  With that in mind, I should have taken $v = (1,1,1)^T = v_1 + v_2$, which would lead to an $S$ of 
$$
S = \pmatrix{1&1/2 & 0\\1 & -1/2 & 0\\1 & 0 & 1}
$$

Comment: @milez if that explanation isn't clear enough, you may want to post your own question

Comment: That is clear, using a linear combination of eigenvectors was the solution! Thank you.